# How to trigger a SQL Agent Job from a client PC

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Agent job that is automated that a non SQL Admin user may need to occasionaly run. I know I can trigger a SQL Agent Job via **sp_execute_job**.

Can anyone tell me where to find what I need installed on a (Non SQL Server box) client PC in order to run one of - SQLCmd, OSQL or ISQL - commands please, so I can execute the above SQL?

I have no issue with what I need to execute in the database, rather the minimum of what I need on the client PC.

Or is there are simpler way perhaps with out calling TSQL or without installing any SQL client tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need something that can log into the database.  Then either you can run sp_execute_job from the msdb database.  If the users don't have the rights to do that themselves, you can create a user which has those rights and have a stored procedure that uses execute as and then starts the job.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the security I was aware of this.  Please see my edit - I know I can execute this SP, what I'm asking is what I need installed on the client's PC in order to issue the command.

Comment: The only thing that needs to be installed on the users PC is something which will allow them to run the needed T/SQL statement.  You can install SQL Server Management Studio, sqlcmd, osql, isql, some app that you have written.  If you take a few minutes it could be triggered by Word, Excel, Access, etc. as well.

Comment: Apologies - my fault I'm not being clear. I was looking for the minimum I need installed on the client's PC. I know I can use use any program that comes from the SQL Server client but I was wondering what the minimum library set I need. For example does windows have enough in it to allow OSQL.exe to run with out any other dependencies being installed?

Comment: Yes, Windows includes the SQL native client and the SQL Server Driver which is enough to make a connection.  I'm not sure if you can just copy osql.exe onto a computer and use it or not.